# Проблема с чтением xml файла

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Имеется xml файл. Который я пытаюсь распечатать в виде таблицы. Однако, когда я пытаюсь просмотреть файл он выдает такую ошибку:

```
error on line 32 at column 10: EntityRef: expecting ';'
```

Эта линия содержит:

```
<name>C&C Адвентэч Гель для умывания 150мл</name>
```

То есть система ругается на `C&C` принимая это за код и выделяя синим. Если удаляю то все в порядке. Но проблема в том, что файл довольно большой и таких знаков много. Есть какой нибудь способ игнорировать этот символ? Еще интересно то, что ругается только если я пытаюсь создать xml файле у себя на локальном хосте. Онлайн версия работает без проблем. Но проблема в том, что у меня не получается получить файл в онлайне.

Используемая функция для получения ссылки:

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "1011.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

То есть в этой линии `mlhttp.open("GET", "1011.xml", true);` если просто `1011.xml` файл на локальном хосте работает,

Но если так `mlhttp.open("GET", "http://provizor.tk/up/1011.xml", true);` то ничего не получается

Comment: Сервер отдает вам эту строчку в виде `<name>C&amp;C ...`, поэтому все работает правильно. а в локальном файле у Вас `<name>C&C ...`. XML-парсер, встречая символ `&`, ожидает, что это начинается html entity, и удивляется, не находя закрывающего символа `;`, о чём, собственно, и сообщает.

Comment: @Yaant Я это понимаю, но что я могу сделать с локальным файлом вот в чем вопрос? или как мне вывести ссылку с серевера?

Comment: Если в файле нет никаких html entities, то можно любым подходящим инструментом произвести в нем глобальную замену символа `&` на `&amp;`. Если есть, тогда всё, конечно, нескольк сложнее, хотя, наверно, тоже можно будет обойтись какими-нибудь регулярными выражениями. А в чем именно у Вас проблема с обращением к серверу, из вопроса не ясно. В консоль какие-нибудь ошибки пишутся? Или под отладчиком посмотреть, какой статус приходит в onreadystatechange (возможно, там почему-либо оказывается не 200).

Comment: @Yaant именно так и сделал. Произвел замену символа. Теперь понимаю, что проблема вовсе не в том, что локальный файл или нет. Так как сейчас и с локальным файлом проблема. Ошибок никаких нет, после нажатия на кнопку просто ничего не происходит. Стоит мне сократить файл на несколько тысяч срок он начинает работать. Стоит увеличить и снова после нажатия кнопки ничего не происходит